# Dynamically change the title of NavDropdown in React using bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, react-bootstrap, nav

I have created a dropdown with ReactBootstrap which have the title of "SIGN IN". I want to dynamically change the title to SIGN OUT when a user is logged in. I have my firebase authorization code already written, but I just want to change the title.

Here is my Home component which contains the NavBar:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Navbar,NavDropdown, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'
import SignIn from './SignIn'


class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="light" >
                    <Navbar.Brand href="/">Home Page</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="mr-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="#features">Home</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">About Us</Nav.Link>
                        <NavDropdown title="Products" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">1</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">2</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">3</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">4</NavDropdown.Item>
                        </NavDropdown>
                        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Contact</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Shop</Nav.Link>

                        </Nav>
                        <Nav>
                        <NavDropdown title="SIGN IN" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="SignIn">User</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="AdminSignIn">Admin</NavDropdown.Item>
                        </NavDropdown>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
        )
    }
}



export default Home
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use state. When the state changes, then the rerender occurs.

Something like

```
const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(false);
let titleHere = signedIn? 'Sign Out': 'Sign In';
```

Then

```
<NavDropdown.Item onClick={(e: any) => {setSignedIn(true)}}>{titleHere}</NavDropdown.Item>
```

When the event is triggered, the state is changed, and the rerender occurs.